# coloring wpf checkbox box C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to coloring the CheckBox box in a WPF app. I tried to type this in XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="topintegral" Content="TOP Integral" `enter code here`
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="188" Margin="94,105,68,86"
          FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Background="Black"
          MouseEnter="MouseFocus" MouseLeave="MouseLeave" BorderBrush="#FFE6FFFF">
```

and in the .cs file:

```
private void MouseFocus(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    topintegral.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

but it shows like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOWid.png)

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it back in the previous state(black color) then do it in the MouseLeave event.

```
    private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        topintegral.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
```

otherwise, your code is working fine.

The MouseFocus method is the event handler of MouseEnter event, so when cursor enters in the checkbox it turns into white. But if you want it back into the previous color just write the event handler of the MouseLeave event.